# Using price source option (PCS) in the BDH formula in R

Tags: r, bloomberg

I have a time series that had its price source changed (from BSCO to BSCN) and I need an entire history of it (it can come in two separate time series it does not matter). I have been trying to compile formulas to get the date but they do not work.

```
BDH("CMSERSBL Index","px_last","24/11/2004","24/11/2015", option_names = "PCS", option_values = "BSCO")

BDH("CMSERSBL Index","px_last","24/11/2004","24/11/2015", option_names = "PCS", option_values = "BSCN")
```

Any ideas how to correct the formulas?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the price source in the ticker:

```
BDH("CMSERSBL BCSO Index","px_last","24/11/2004","24/11/2015")
```

Also note that it is `BCSO`, and not `BSCO` as in your example.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I tried this many times but it does not seem to work. I actually got the correct formula myself: Bdh("CMSECLBL Index","px_last",st.date,end.date, overrides = structure("BSCO",names="PRICING_SOURCE"). But the issue now is when I run exactly the same code without changing anything at all sometimes I get data with old price source and the other times with new price source. It changes just randomly. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: @pirmunas I don't have R so I'm doing it in Excel and it works as expected. I don't think I can help you much more than that I'm afraid...